# When does the Undo History Stack get cleared for MS Office Files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

For MS Office Products in general (or specific products in particular, my main focus is Word/Excel/Power Point). Running Office 365 or Later. What causes the undo stack to clear?

If I wanted to deliberately clear the stack, how would I do it?

If I wanted to deliberately preserve the stack, how would I do it?

---

If it helps, my specific concern right now is sharing files with a 3rd party, and making sure that they only have access to the final version, not anything we did in the files before sharing them.

Comment: "my specific concern right now is sharing files with a 3rd party, and making sure that they only have access to the final version" The saved and transferred file won't maintain the undo history, the history is all local to your environment.

Comment: As far as I know undo history isn't stored in the file. If you close the file, the history is gone. The only sources of unintended disclosable information (that I know of) that are  retained are the document properties, cropped images, hidden columns / rows or slides, and tracked changes in "final" view. I sometimes "file > save as" as new file to throw out cropped areas & ghost information. If you want to be super cautious, do a test. Save some info, remove it and save / save as again. Then rename the office file to zip. Unzip and search the contents of the xml text files for the info.

Comment: @spikey_richie I thought that was the case, but I couldn't really find anything that explicitly stated it. You could post that as an answer.

Comment: Tracked changes are stored inside the document and you can undo using that feature. Others can too, so its not computer specific. Its disabled by default though, so its likely turned off for your document.

Comment: @LPChip That could also be an answer ^^

Comment: @Kaz Not directly related to your question but something that might also be of concern when sharing files:  If you've embedded content from another file, e.g. even just a few characters of text from an Excel file, the *entire* source file is included in the PPT/PPTX. Someone else can very easily view and even save a copy of the source file on their own computer.  If you don't want to give people access to the embedded content, ungrouping it will generally solve the problem.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg What exactly do you mean by embedding? Is that copying? Data Links? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @Kaz Not links; if you copy something in another app and paste it into PoewrPoint, one of the paste options might be to embed the copied data. Depending on the version of Office, when you copy/paste from Excel to PPT, the default may be to embed the file. If the file's embedded, there are no links, but you can still edit the embedded data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted as answer already, the undo history (pressing the undo button, or hitting CTRL-Z) is a per-session based action that uses the memory of your system at any given point in time. When you close your document, this history is purged too. So reopening a document means the undo history is gone. For that reason, the undo history cannot be sent to others even if you wanted to.

Tracked Changes however is a document feature. This feature enables version history for a particular document and stores all changes in the file itself. Using the track changes feature, one can then see if the changes are wanted or not, compare with the before state, and once satisfied, accept the changes.

Until the changes are accepted, the before and after state can be seen as well as what area was changed until Tracked Changes is disabled and either the changes have been accepted or rejected.

Do note, by default Tracked Changes is set to off, so it is likely that this is not on for you anyway, but given that you want to ensure that no changes can be seen, you should verify if Tracked Changes is indeed turned off. Depending on your version of Office, its either accessible after you share the workbook/document, or accessible through Review->Track Changes.

Answer (score 1):

> My specific concern right now is sharing files with a 3rd party, and making sure that they only have access to the final version"

The saved and transferred file won't maintain the undo history, the history is all local to your environment.

Comment: I take it from this that there is in fact no way to preserve the Undo History even if you wanted to?

Comment: the moment you close the document, the undo history is gone. No way to preserve that. You can save and undo after, but as soon as the document is closed and reopened, its gone. If Track changes is turned on, the changes can be undone using that feature even AFTER you close the document and reopen. Track Changes is a property of the document, and can be shipped to another computer/person. This is disabled by default though.